# Interstial Ads not showing

Tags: android, interstitial

> Test `Interstitial` ads load but when i **replace  my Ad Id**. `Interstitial ads` doesn't load.  And also  tell me whether to  comment or not this statement. `addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")`

**In onCreate:**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8969610320924197/4577744862");

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed()
    {
        super.onAdClosed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded()
    {
        super.onAdLoaded();

        if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
        {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
});

requestNewInterstitial();
```

Where

```
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                  //.addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                  .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

and in manifest i include

```
 <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

and in application tag.

```
 <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

         <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Where i am doing wrong? 
How to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an **emulator** to test your app, then you should use this line:

```
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
```

If you're using your **real phone**, then you should find your device ID on the logcat. It will be shown probably when it tryies to load an add or show it, you'll have to keep an eye on logcat.

Note that this is for test purposes only, meaning that you could test the app without the `addTestDevice()` line, but it's not allowed by Admob's policy.